# Application of laws of limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Could someone explain me how the author applied the limit and then took the power. According to limit Laws, it is valid when the exponent is any positive integer but here it is a function of $x$ and $x$ is approaching towards infinity, so why did the author apply it here.

> 1.10.6. Find
> $$
> \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)^{x}
> $$
> *Solution* $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)^{x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)^{x^{2}}\right]^{1 / x}=e^{0}=1$

Book - I.A. Maron Problems in Calculus of One Variable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), rather than images, as they're not searchable.

Comment: Please visit [mathjax tutorial especially written for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) and typeset math using it.

Comment: Using properties of exponential and logarithmic functions it can be proved that if $f(x) \to a, g(x) \to b$ and $a>0$ then $(f(x)) ^{g(x)} \to a^b$. The textbook should discuss this before presenting this example. If this is not done, it is a common case of intellectual dishonesty.

Comment: Anyway Maron's book is just a problem book so you can't expect it to contain any conceptual discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Before evaluating a limit and algebra done is valid regardless of the value that it will take, and it is true that:
$$f(x)^{x}=\left(f(x)^{x^2}\right)^{1/x}$$
What is happening after that is they are using the fact that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1{x^2}\right)^{x^2}=e$$
then:
$$e^{1/x}\to 1$$

Answer (score 0):

From your photo, it appears the author of your book gives no explanation of the steps made, so I won't guess at what I.A. Maron had in mind. But I see you are anxious to justify the result, so I will try to give a more rigorous answer.

I define $g(x)\,=\,(1+\frac{1}{x^2})^{x^2},\,\,$ and $f(x)\,=\,\frac{1}{x}.\,\,$
We wish to show:$\,\,\,\,g(x)^{f(x)}\,\to\,1,\,\,\,\,$ as $x \to +\infty.$

For us $g(x)>1$,   since $x$ big and positive.

Note that $x \mapsto \log x$ is continuous.

$$g(x)^{f(x)}\,\,=\,\,e^{f(x)\log{g(x)}},$$

$${f(x)\log{g(x)}}\,\,\to\,\,(0)(\log e)\,\,=\,\,0.$$

Finally, noting $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous,

$$g(x)^{f(x)}\,\,=\,\,e^{f(x)\log{g(x)}}\,\,\to\,\,e^{(0)(\log e)}\,\,=1.$$

Comment: Consider a function h(x) = f(x)^g(x) now as x approaches a, f(x) approaches 1 and g(x) approaches infinity. But according to the example if we apply limit separately to f(x) and g(x) then we will get indeterminate form (1^infinity) and we need to use e^lim{(f(x)-1)g(x)}. So I want to ask when we can apply the limits separately to f(x) and g(x) and when we can't.